# Angular2 with Typescript - mqtt.js doesn't find client

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mqtt

I have a specific problem. I am trying to implement the mqtt.js library in angular2 with typescript. Here's my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
 private client: mqtt.Client;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.connectToMQTTBroker();
  }
  public connectToMQTTBroker () {
    console.log('trying to connect');
    this.client  = mqtt.connect('ws://mqttBroker.de:1882');
    this.client.addListener('connect', this.on_connect);
    this.client.addListener('message', this.on_message);
  }

  private on_connect () {
    console.log('connected');
    this.client.subscribe('/broker/response/clientID');
    this.client.publish('/providers', '{...Message...}' );
  }

  private on_message (args: any[]) {
    console.log(args[0]);
    console.log(args[1]);
  }
}
```

It connects succesfully, I see the 'connected' message in the log, but then I get `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

Why is the client variable not accessible in the on_connect method? I am pretty sure I am missing some basic Typescript stuff, but I just cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the this binding (https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md).
Try by replacing

```
this.client.addListener('connect', this.on_connect);
this.client.addListener('message', this.on_message);
```

with

```
this.client.addListener('connect', this.on_connect.bind(this));
this.client.addListener('message', this.on_message.bind(this);
```

or with

```
this.client.addListener('connect', () => {this.on_connect()});
this.client.addListener('message', (args) => {this.on_message(args)});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are running into is that `this` has changed inside the scope of your `on_connect` message. This has to do with how TypeScript handles the assignment of `this` when using arrow notation, or not, in a callback function. Update your call back bindings to be the following:

```
this.client.addListener('connect', () => this.on_connect());
this.client.addListener('message', () => this.on_message());
```

By not using the arrow notation in your original definition TypeScript does not handle the scope binding for you when it Transpiles and so the `this` inside of the `on_connect` function refers to the function itself.